# What is 'advanced report configuration' and when will it work?

Tags: reports, 5.13

I was updating a report when I noticed a link to 'advanced report configuration' (this was on release 5.13.5).  Following that link I got a screen similar to the contact layout editor - but I couldn't make anything work.  After an upgrade to 5.17.4 this link has disappeared.  It looked very useful & interesting, allowing columns to have the title changed plus other stuff.  I guess I stumbled on something that's not ready yet - or is this an extension I've missed?  If not - any ideas when this will be implemented?

Comment: I've seen the same issue as you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is part of Extended Reports, and appears on some (not all) extended reports.  Notably, it allows you to change the order of columns in your report.  This works for me.

Comment: Thanks Jon. At present changing column order seems to be the only feature. Looks very useful and promising.